# Rails: how to organize code - when to use services

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models: user, employee. `User has_one :employee`, Employee `belongs_to :user`
In my app:

- employee is always a user
- there can be user that is not an employee
- employee and user have email as unique identifier

So - when employee is created i need to check if there is aready a user with the same email

- Yes - update employee with user_id
- No - create user and update employee with user_id.

The code to do it is simple. But i wonder where in the app structure it should go:

- i can do it in employee model (`after_create` method) - but i will have to refer to User model in Employee model (is that correct)?
- i can everything in employee_controller - but i would not like to put business logic inside controllers...
- i can create an extra class (i.e. in services folder) named `user_service` with a `create_user_for_employee(employee)` method - and call it inside create action in my employee_controller

Which solution is the best? or there is another one - better? Is "services" a correct name for a folder with such classes? i assume that when application growths, i will need more classes and methods like that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services in Rails have several reasons to be introduced. And one of them matches your use case pretty well - it is to use service when the operation you need to implement is related to more than one model.

Since your operation is related to `User` and `Employee` service is definitely may be your choice.

Yes, `services` is a good name for the folder. And yes, while your app growing you may end up with many classes out of MVC pattern, for example services, decorators, forms etc.

Feel free to check [7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) for further reading. That article is a sort of canonical.